# How to install an own/custom patch in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2-esb

We have detected a possible bug in WSO2 ESB 4.8.0 and have found a sustainable  work-around for this problem. Now we want to contact WSO2 to report this bug because it impedes our project.

In the meantime we have to modify a class in axis2_1.6.1-wso2v10.jar to avoid the disadvantageous behavior of the tool.

A dropping of the modified JAR into one of the lib folders has no effect. Also we aren't sure if we should create an own patch below directory ~/repository/components/patches. Our first try to do so has failed.

What is the recommended way to (temporarily) install an own/custom patch in the ESB until we get an official patch from WSO2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 officially describes the Patch Application Process at page https://docs.wso2.org/display/EMM110/WSO2+Patch+Application+Process

"...The WSO2 patch application process is automated from WSO2 Carbon 4.2.0 release onwards. You can simply place your service pack (e.g., servicepack001) in /repository/components/servicepacks directory and restart the server. To revert the service pack, remove it from the service directory..."

Answer (score 0):

You may try dropping the updated jar in "/repository/components/plugins" folder instead lib and replacing the existing jar.
Also report the bug to WSo2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it's not sufficient to drop the modified jar into the "/repository/components/plugins" folder. Afterwards we got several ClassCastExceptions. - However We were now successful after we installed our own patch in "~/repository/components/patches" and dropped the modified JAR file into the "/repository/components/plugins" folder. - Nevertheless we still aren't sure if this is the recommended approach.

Answer (score 0):

if replace jars in "/repository/components/plugins" make sure put the exact name. Your modified jar should have same name axis2_1.6.1-wso2v10.jar --> axis2_1.6.1.wso2v10.jar